# FailedPreconditionError when saving the model in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, mnist

I am running a function 'train' in which I am trying to save my model using

```
    save_path = saver.save(sess, model_path,global_step=1000)
    print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
```

where model_path is the parameter passed to function 'train' (along with several other parameters which define my neural network)

```
    model_path="Models/LeNet"
```

I want to save the models for different set of parameters for a comparison. So when I run the function in a loop, sometimes it , but sometimes I get the following error

```
 FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Failed to rename: Models/LeNet-1000.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate4653798046453900544 to: Models/LeNet-1000.data-00000-of-00001 : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

 [[Node: save/SaveV2 = SaveV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/SaveV2/tensor_names, save/SaveV2/shape_and_slices, Model/b1, Model/b1/Adam, Model/b1/Adam_1, Model/b2, Model/b2/Adam, Model/b2/Adam_1, Model/b3, Model/b3/Adam, Model/b3/Adam_1, Model/b4, Model/b4/Adam, Model/b4/Adam_1, Model/b5, Model/b5/Adam, Model/b5/Adam_1, Model/w1, Model/w1/Adam, Model/w1/Adam_1, Model/w2, Model/w2/Adam, Model/w2/Adam_1, Model/w3, Model/w3/Adam, Model/w3/Adam_1, Model/w4, Model/w4/Adam, Model/w4/Adam_1, Model/w5, Model/w5/Adam, Model/w5/Adam_1, SGD/beta1_power, SGD/beta2_power)]]
```

I am wondering why it creates a file with the extension 'tempstate4653798046453900544' and why it says 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process' even though I tried closing all the processes in my computer except jupyter notebook.  Note that this error is different than 'Tensorflow FailedPreconditionError, but all variables have been initialized'.

I am attaching my train function here:

```
def train(learning_rate, training_epochs, batch_size, display_step, alg, actFun, logs_path,model_path):

tf.reset_default_graph()

# tf Graph Input:  mnist data image of shape 28*28=784
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name='InputData')
# 0-9 digits recognition,  10 classes
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name='LabelData')

with tf.name_scope('Model'):
    # Model
    xin=tf.reshape(x,[-1,28,28,1]) # reshape the input image to 28x28 size
    pred = LeNet5_Model(xin,actFun)
with tf.name_scope('Loss'):
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=pred))  
    print ('cost',cost)
with tf.name_scope('SGD'):
    optimizer = alg(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):
    # Accuracy
    acc = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(acc, tf.float32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

tf.summary.scalar("Loss", cost)
tf.summary.scalar("Accuracy", acc)
merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    train_writer= tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path+'/train', graph=tf.get_default_graph())
    validation_writer= tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path+'/validation', graph=tf.get_default_graph())
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size, shuffle=True)
            _, c, acc_train, summary = sess.run([optimizer, cost, acc, merged_summary_op],
                                     feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys})
            train_writer.add_summary(summary, epoch * total_batch + i)
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
        accValid, summary_validation= sess.run([acc,merged_summary_op],feed_dict={x: X_validation, y: y_validation})
        validation_writer.add_summary(summary_validation, epoch)     
        if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch: ", '%02d' % (epoch+1), "  ====> Loss=", "{:.6f}".format(avg_cost), "Training Accuracy=","{:.6f}".format(acc_train*100),"%", " Validation Accuracy=","{:.6f}".format(accValid*100),"%")   
    print("Optimization Finished!") 
    save_path = saver.save(sess, model_path,global_step=1000)
    print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
```

Comment: Is it possible that another file with the same name already exists?

Comment: The error occured due to saving the model in Dropbox folder. Courtesy to  [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9090)

Comment: @PramodBachhav Were you able to solve the problem. I am experiencing the same?

Comment: @user1700890 Yes. The key is to turn off dropbox update untill the  saving operation is done or save the result file somewhere else. Please refer to [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9090).